# Computed Property not rerendering

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, computed-properties

When a component data value ( which is array with objects ) changes the computed property is not affected.

In the example below, I have a table that is filled with some data ( it is tasks in different statuses with titles ). If you click on a task and you click the button 'CHANGE TASK INFO' it will change the current task selected to

```
{
    Status = QA Review
    Title = TEST
}
```

However if you comment the 99,100 lines and uncomment the 96 line the things are not the same anymore if you try to click the button with a different task selected the task is updated in the 'tasks' variable of the component but never rerendered by the computed prop.

Any ideas ?

SB
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-table-test-enviroment-bx1sd?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue is not able to detect changes if you replace an array item by index (see [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)).

The solution is simple:

```js
this.$set(this.tasks, indexOfUpdatedTask, test);
```